# Sqoop Understanding with MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, apache-zookeeper, sqoop

What is the minimal size to import data through sqoop,
while i'm using sqoop for bulk import with regular interval mapreduce got crashed and i cant able to access any data in my datanodes

and tell me what are the basic configurations need to done for sqoop bulk import

I cant troubleshoot the cluster

And when i start using sqoop -import command

```
13/11/30 01:12:57 WARN db.TextSplitter: Generating splits for a textual index column.
13/11/30 01:12:57 WARN db.TextSplitter: If your database sorts in a case-insensitive order, this may result in a partial import or duplicate records.
13/11/30 01:12:57 WARN db.TextSplitter: You are strongly encouraged to choose an integral split column.
```

any issue with the above one,,

Thanks for ur attention

Comment: What is version of Sqoop you are using ? And what is the errors/exceptions ?

Comment: i'm using 1.4.3, while i bulk import 2lakh through script at sequential manner my mapreduce getting fail to map data,after some while i cant able read any data in hbase...

Comment: Please do share entire Sqoop log generated with parameter --verbose.